# Where is ros-groovy in macports

Tags: ros-groovy, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to ROS and I am trying to install it in MAC OSX 10.7.5 using ports.
After executing this command
sudo port install ros-groovy

I get the following error:
Error: Port ros-groovy not found

Any idea why. I am following the instructions as specified in here the mac port installation page

Any help appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/82901/where-is-ros-groovy-in-macports/) by [chiko](https://answers.ros.org/users/7041/chiko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the real problem is that you can't 'sudo port ros-groovy' because there is no port with that exact name- you need to specify the full name, such as ros-groovy-core, etc.

The order of the file URL and rsync is necessary as well, as noted by rleontie.

---

Originally posted by [cyberguy42](https://answers.ros.org/users/5314/cyberguy42/) with karma: 188 on 2014-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0